# What can we do to combat (potential) organized spams from an organization?

Tags: discussion, spam

Recently, I came across several spam posts that seems to be posted by the same organisation:

1. [Chat GPT Gratuit : Révolutionnant la Communication Virtuelle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77505964/chat-gpt-gratuit-r%c3%a9volutionnant-la-communication-virtuelle)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77484987/chatgpt-nederlands-toekomstige-ontwikkelingen-en-mogelijkheden
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77334649/chat-gpt-r%c3%a9volution-de-lintelligence-artificielle

Observations:

1. The posts are written in non-English languages; potentially to elude spam detection
2. The posts seem to be coming from the same organization. Although every time new accounts are created to post new spam posts, the accounts share the same icon.

Currently, I am flagging them as spam so they can be removed. Is there any way(s) we can block similar organized spam more effectively?

Comment: A watch is added for the domains they spam: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64733604#64733604

Comment: I see one similar post has already become a review audit :D

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In addition to flagging as spam...

We have a project called [Charcoal](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/06/25/how-does-spam-protection-work-on-stack-exchange/) that allows you to participate in spam blocking. You could join that project and report any spam posts you find there. They will track the organisation that is posting the spam too and pick up any additional posts that mention it, they are perfectly capable of tracking non-English spam.

Comment: The OP can also join the [autoflagging program](https://charcoal-se.org/flagging) and "lend" their spam flagging capability to the detection system.